# Unmarshalling nested xml to struct

Tags: xml, go, struct

How does one create a struct in Go for nested xml content?
Imagine this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people>
  <person>
    <name>Pers1</name>
    <gender>female</gender>
    <somethings>
      <thing>123</thing>
      <thing>321</thing>
    </somethings>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Pers2</name>
    <gender>male</gender>
    <somethings>
      <thing>111</thing>
      <thing>222</thing>
      <thing>333</thing>
    </somethings>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Pers3</name>
    <gender>female</gender>
    <somethings>
      <thing>978</thing>
    </somethings>
  </person>
  <!-- And so on... -->
</people>
```

I'm able to load the data but I can't manage to create a struct for this kind of nested data. Every trick you have would be good to know!

Have a good day! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type Data struct {
    People []Person `xml:"person"`
}

type Person struct {
    Name       string   `xml:"name"`
    Gender     string   `xml:"gender"`
    Somethings []string `xml:"somethings>thing"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/q2CKAfiiwQ

Comment: Oh man that's embarrassing, don't know why I could come up with that. Thank you!